# jQuery selectable preventing click event to propagate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js, marionette

I am working on a Backbone.Marionette app. I have a `CompositeView` in which I insert `ItemView`s (which are `li`s) into a `ul`.

I have bound to `click` event of the `li`s in my `ItemView`:

```
class MyView extends Marionette.ItemView
  events:
    "click" : "doSomething"
  doSomething: ->
    console.log "Doing something"
```

Now, I also use jQuery's Selectable to enable selectig the `li`s.

```
$("ul").selectable()
```

The problem is that when the `li` is clicked (and selected by jQuery), it prevents the `click` event to propagate and fire `doSomething`.

I wonder if there is someway to stop jQuery from stoping the `click` event?

Comment: See my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419263/propagation-issue-in-nested-jquery-ui-selectable/46819120#46819120

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There most likely isn't an easy way to achieve exactly what you want: Selectable probably stops propagation of the click event. What you could to however, is use another event triggered by selectable, such as "start" (http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#event-start) :

```
class MyView extends Marionette.ItemView
  events:
    "start" : "doSomething"
  doSomething: ->
    console.log "Doing something"
```